# softkeyboard predictive text overlap text area

Tags: android

i am playing with android soft keyboard example.but the problem i m getting predictive text area overlap the edit text box. I tried both

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" 
and 
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustpan" but nothing

Answer (score 1):

That's a problem with the keyboard.  The keyboard implements a function onComputeInsets, which provides a visible inset and a content inset.  If they make the visible inset bigger than the content inset, the difference will always overlap the app.  There's no way for the app to fix this.  You can see that if you switch to a different keyboard that likely won't happen.